# obtain individual coefficent value from clogit in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survival-analysis, coefficients

Lets take the conditional logisitc regression example from the [Survival Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/survival.pdf)

And using the following commands

```
library(survival)

data(logan)

resp <- levels(logan$occupation)
n <- nrow(logan)
indx <- rep(1:n, length(resp))
logan2 <- data.frame(logan[indx,],
                     id = indx,
                     tocc = factor(rep(resp, each=n)))
logan2$case <- (logan2$occupation == logan2$tocc)
B <- clogit(case ~ tocc + tocc:education + strata(id), logan2)
```

Now we can generate the regression parameters, but lets say we specifically want the `toccfarm` value of -1.896.

How would we only output this or save it as `x` save this.

When we use

```
B$coefficients
```

we get all the regression coefficients.

I have tried something like

```
B$coefficients[1,]
B$coefficients(term=1)
B$coefficients("toccfarm")
```

But none have worked

Comment: `B$coefficients[1]` or `coef(B)[1]` or `B$coefficients['toccfarm']`
 should work

Comment: yes I have just found an example of coef() function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another approach can be with the use of the `summary` function. You can see that with summary the coefficients of the model are taken as a matrix.

```
> is.matrix(summary(B)$coefficients)
[1] TRUE
```

At this point you can store `summary(B)$coefficients` in an object and then subset it as you wish.

```
summary(B)$coefficients[1,1]
```